# How to draw svg in openlayers map

Tags: javascript, html, css, openlayers

I am working on an example map project and I have used [openlayers map](https://openlayers.org/).
Now I need to implement flight animation like this article [flight animation](http://www.tnoda.com/blog/2014-04-02/) flight svg icon.
But I don't know how to draw on openlayers map in flight svg and animation. Could anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far.

Comment: Here is some code  https://codesandbox.io/s/flight-animation-swhzr to add icons to this OpenLayers example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/flight-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

As per you question you want some animation on Icon in Openlayers map. They already have an [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-animation.html). Here is the refernce of adding the icon :-

```
var style = new Style({
  image: new CircleStyle({
    radius: radius,
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, ' + opacity + ')',
      width: 0.25 + opacity
    })
  })
});
```